# JSON Server router

Tags: javascript, json, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to get a polymer web page login to work but seemingly I can't since app.js cannot read the JSON database defined within the file itself. I have uploaded a screenshot of how my folders and files are layered in Visual Studio Code. I'm using a Windows 10 NT OS and Git Bash to run my commands.

***THIS IS THE GIT BASH ERROR***

> Rhino@DESKTOP-NB42TJJ MINGW64
>   /c/users/rhino/documents/work/personal/polymer-project $ node
>   demo-server/app.js JSON Server is runnning TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'users' of undefined
>       at C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\demo-server\app.js:34:33
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>       at next (C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>       at C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\demo-server\app.js:29:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\users\rhino\documents\work\personal\polymer-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

***THIS IS MY app.js file***

```
    var express = require("../node_modules/express");
    var app = express();
    var path    = require("path");

    var jsonServer = require("../node_modules/json-server");
    var server = jsonServer.create();
    var router = jsonServer.router('db.json');


    //Authentication Libraries  -  Start
    var cookieParser = require('../node_modules/cookie-parser');
    var session = require('../node_modules/express-session');
    //Authentication Libraries - End

    server.use(cookieParser("security", {"path": "/"}));
    app.use(cookieParser("security", {"path": "/"}));

    server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access

-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT,   OPTIONS");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
    "X-Custom-Header,X-Requested-With,X-Prototype-Version,Content-Type,Cache-      Control,Pragma,Origin,content-type");

    if (!req.signedCookies.usersession && req._parsedUrl.pathname !=    "/auth/login" && req.method != "OPTIONS") {
        res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/app/pages/auth/auth.html');
     }else{
        next();
    }
});

    server.post('/auth/login', function(req, res){
    var users = router.db.object.users;
    var username = req.query.username;
    var password = req.query.password;
    for(var i=0;i<=users.length -1;i++){
        if(users[i].username == username && users[i].password == password) {
            res.cookie('usersession', users[i].id, {maxAge: 9000000,    httpOnly: false, signed: true});
            res.send(JSON.stringify({success: true}));
            return;
        }
    }
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: 'Wrong username or password' }));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if (!req.signedCookies.usersession) {
        res.redirect('app/pages/auth/auth.html');
    }else{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/../app/index.html'));
    }
});

app.get('/auth/logout', function(req, res){
    res.clearCookie('usersession');
    res.redirect('/app/pages/auth/auth.html');
});
/*app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/../app/index.html'));
});
*/

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../')));
var http = require('http').Server(app);
http.listen(8080);

server.use(jsonServer.defaults); //logger, static and cors middlewares
server.use(router); //Mount router on '/'
server.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('JSON Server is runnning')
});
```

[Picture of Visual Studio Code project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUcjp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add middleware as follow in your code:

```
var jsonServer   = require('../node_modules/json-server');
var server       = jsonServer.create();
var router       = jsonServer.router('db.json');
var middlewares  = jsonServer.defaults(); //<--- new line
```

then in your server.use(jsonServer.defaults); //logger, static and cors middlewares, inject middleware as shown:

```
server.use(middlewares); //logger, static and cors middleware
```